# Toggling div based on radiobutton

Tags: jquery, forms, radio-button, jquery-animate

Hi i just need to untangle my jQuery.

I need to show the next div after the radio button if the radio button is checked. and hide everything else.

this is my html:

```
<div class="radio-perk">
    <input class="perkdrop" id="tab1" type="radio" name="amount" value="250">
    <label for="tab1">10 frames</label>
</div>   // I added this as it seemed to be missing @ManseUK
<div id="tabs-250" class="dropdown">
    <p>2131</p>
</div>
<div class="radio-perk">
    <input class="perkdrop" id="tab2" type="radio" name="amount" value="400">
    <label for="tab2">1 sekund, DVD</label>
</div>
<div id="tabs-400" class="dropdown">
    <p>123</p>
</div>
<div class="radio-perk">
    <input class="perkdrop" id="tab3" type="radio" name="amount" value="600">
    <label for="tab3">Invitasjon Wrapfest</label>
</div>
<div id="tabs-600" class="dropdown">
    <p>2342</p>
</div>
<div class="radio-perk">
    <input class="perkdrop" id="tab4" type="radio" name="amount" value="900">
    <label for="tab4">Invitasjon f&oslash;rpremiere</label>
</div>
<div id="tabs-900" class="dropdown">
    <p>223</p>
</div>
<div class="radio-perk">
    <input class="perkdrop" id="tab5" type="radio" name="amount" value="1200">
    <label for="tab5">En dag p&aring; settet</label>
</div>
<div id="tabs-1200" class="dropdown">
    <p>23132</p>
</div>
<div class="radio-perk">
    <input class="perkdrop" id="tab6" type="radio" name="amount" value="1600">
    <label for="tab6">To dager p&aring; settet</label>
</div>
<div id="tabs-1600" class="dropdown">
    <p>23123</p>
</div>
<div class="radio-perk">
    <input class="perkdrop" id="tab7" type="radio" name="amount" value="2500">
    <label for="tab7">Assosiate Producer</label>
</div>
<div id="tabs-2500" class="dropdown">
    <p>23312</p>
</div>
```

And this is my jQuery so far:

```
$(".perkdrop").change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).next("div").slideToggle("normal");
    }
});
```

and this is my relevant css:

```
.dropdown {
   display: none;
}
```

I can't understand why i can select the next div item? And how do i get everything else to close? Any help is appreciated

Comment: I have updated the code in your question as you were missing a `</div>` after the first `input` ... is this correct or is there really a missing `</div>` in the actual HTML ?

Comment: I misplaced a div tag. due to past experimentation, thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like below,

```
$(".perkdrop").change(function() {
    $('.dropdown').slideUp();
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).parent().next().slideToggle("normal");
    }
});
```

Also I think you messed up the first group div (the structure is different from other). which I think is not the case.

http://jsfiddle.net/DBexG/2/

Comment: He is not missing `</div>`, he has strange markup. For the first node we need to use `siblings()`, for other nodes -- `parent().next()`... o_O

Comment: @VisioN i have just corrected that in the OPs question thinking it was a mistake ... will rollback the change ....

Comment: No need to roll back. :) It is a misplaced div from previous experimentation.

Comment: This works thank you :) the only problem i still face is that the animation jumps at the end when i have multiple lines of text inside the div. Got any solution for that? :) Thanks BTW I'll accept in 2 min (limitation).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $(".perkdrop").change(function() {
    $('.dropdown').hide();
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).parent().next(".dropdown").slideToggle("normal");
    }

 });​
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/PgEkA/)

Answer (score 0):

The `.next()` function looks for elements at the same level of the DOM as the other elements in the jQuery object. Since your radio button is inside a div, you actually want to do the following:

```
$(this).parent().next('div').slideToggle('normal');
```

In order to close all the other divs, you can select them before that line using a standard class selector, then either `.slideUp()` or `.hide()`, depending on whether you want to animate the closing. The full thing would look like this:

```
$(".perkdrop").change(function() {
    if(this.checked)  {
        $('.dropdown').slideUp();
        $(this).next("div").slideToggle("normal");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`.next()` only searches siblings ... try this

```
$(".perkdrop").change(function() {
    $(".dropdown").slideUp('normal');  // slide up all open divs
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        // get parent (div) then next DOM element with class "dropdown"
        $(this).parent().next('.dropdown').slideToggle("normal");
    }
});​
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/nSbmx/)